Getting cors error even after using "CORS(app, origins="http://localhost:3000")" in my code
I'm getting cors error in my code even after enabling cors in the backend.
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins="http://localhost:3000")

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.flask_database

medicine = db.medicine

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])  # Allow OPTIONS method
def handle_example():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.json
        name = data.get('name')
        return "hello"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


the above entered code is the code I've given in my app.py file.
I've used CORS(app, origins="http://localhost:3000")
in my code but the error is still present.
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/", {
      method: "Post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body:JSON.stringify(Cart)
    })
      .then((response) => {
        // Handle the response from the Flask backend
        console.log("Response from Flask:", response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle any errors that occur during the request
        console.log("Error:", error);
      });


this is the code present in the frontend. The error i get is.

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.


Does this answer your question? No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API

Try to create a dedicated route for handling OPTIONS requests.

First you can remove OPTIONS method in POST method. It should works.
If that method is necessary you can add this method to hook request before go to actual routes
from flask import Response

@app.before_request
def hook_request():
    if request.method == "OPTIONS":
        return Response()

Full code is like this
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, Response
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins="http://localhost:3000")


@app.before_request
def hook_request():
    if request.method == "OPTIONS":
        return Response()


@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "OPTIONS"])  # Allow OPTIONS method
def handle_example():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.json
        return jsonify({"data": data})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


